# excel convert class schedule into workload

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am a teacher who needs to convert some class schedule into workload, in Excel. But I would like to make it to automatically convert. See the table below, where BEFORE letters M-A-N (Morning, Afternoon, Night) are the weekdays: [2 = monday, 3 = : tuesday, 4 = wednesday, 5 = thursday, 6 = friday], and the numbers AFTER M-A-N are the *ordered* number of classes of 50 minutes each). I give below and example:

| Classes | Workload | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 246M23 | 6 | --> 3 days a week, Morning, 2 classes each (2nd and 3rd class times) = 6 |
| 2N12 | 2 | --> 1 day a week, Night, 2 classes (1st and 2nd class times) = 2 |
| 3A123 | 3 | --> 1 day a week, Afternoon, 3 classes (1st, 2nd and 3rd class times) = 3 |
| 24A34 | 4 | --> 2 days a week, Afternoon, 2 classes each (3rd and 4th class times) = 4 |

So which formula can I use in Excel to convert the first column (Classes) into the second (Workload)? I gave only a small example, I have a LOT of rows to convert. In summary, I want the product of the number of days (number of digits before letters MAN) TIMES the number of classes (number of digits AFTER MAN).  Thanks in advance!

I tried but I could not find an algorithm or formula to do it. I tried to use RIGHT and LEFT but the numbers before M-A-N change in length so I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `TEXTBEFORE()` & `RIGHT()` functions:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=--RIGHT(TEXTBEFORE(A2:A5,{"M","A","N"}))
```

---

With Older Versions one could try:

[image]

---

```
=--RIGHT(LEFT(A2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND({"M";"A";"N"},A2),""))-1))
```

---

Or,

```
=--MID(A2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND({"M";"A";"N"},A2),""))-1,1)
```

---

**Edit:**

As per OP:

> *Thank you so much for your help! But unfortunately it didn't work :-(*
> *I am using Excel from Office 365, portuguese version. Below you can*
> *find the error: dropbox.com/scl/fi/21x49m87e4x40o0fj8c1k/…*

---

In Portuguese Version of Excel:

[image]

---

```
=--DIREITA(TEXTBEFORE(A2:A5;{"M"."A"."N"}))
```

---

Or

```
=--EXT.TEXTO(A2;MÁXIMO(SEERRO(PROCURAR({"M";"A";"N"};A2);""))-1;1)
```

---

Or,

```
=--DIREITA(ESQUERDA(A2;MÁXIMO(SEERRO(PROCURAR({"M";"A";"N"};A2);""))-1))
```

---

**Caveat:** The formulas for older versions may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode, its `Excel` dependent, `MS365` or `Excel 2021` users don't require that.

---

**EDIT as per new update in OP**

> *In summary, I want the product of the number of days (number of digits*
> *before letters MAN) TIMES the number of classes (number of digits*
> *AFTER MAN).*

---

[image]

---

```
=PRODUCT(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"M","A","N"})))
```

---

Spill Version for whole range:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",A2:A15,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,PRODUCT(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(y,{"M","A","N"})))))),1)
```

---

Or,

```
=BYROW(A2:A15,LAMBDA(x, CONCAT(PRODUCT(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(x,{"M","A","N"}))))))+0
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But unfortunately it didn't work :-( I am using Excel from Office 365, portuguese version. Below you can find the error:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/21x49m87e4x40o0fj8c1k/Sem-t-tulo.png?rlkey=hbiko396yu0qb1l91qq3b573l&dl=1

Comment: @YttriaTherbium you need to change the separators as semicolon in place of comma, see I have updated in answers

Comment: If I am reading your formula correctly, are you simply returning the last digit before the letter as the workload?

Comment: Numbers before `M` , `A`, & `N`

Comment: The digit before M, A or N represents the day of the week from OPS question.  It coincidently corresponds to his work load value

Comment: Thanks!! It is ALMOST working. Some cells give the wrong result, as you can see in yellow in (I replaced A by T here in my portuguese spreadsheet): 

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zwlecrgo7swwic9jrspay/Captura-de-tela-2023-12-08-195734.png?rlkey=ja310ygl4mow352xze7pg5r02&dl=0

Comment: @YttriaTherbium as per your OP, you have said, _where BEFORE letters M-A-N (Morning, Afternoon, Night) are the weekdays: [2 = monday, 3 = : tuesday, 4 = wednesday, 5 = thursday, 6 = friday],_ so what should be the value for `35M56` or `35T12` or `4T123`? So according to you does the yellow ones not correct, if so then it contradicts your statements in the post, can you explain further

Comment: Please see cell D11 in the figure. It reads 3T34, so it is only TWO classes, on tuesday afternoon (in english, 3A34), but cell E11 (the formula) gives 3!

Comment: In the figure, cell D9 reads 4T123 (4A123 in english), so it is 3 classes, but cell E9 gives 4.

Comment: Dear Mayukh, sorry for any confusion I made. The rationale was captured correctly by @Forward Ed below. I want the product of the number of days (number of digits before letters MAN) TIMES the number of classes (number of digits AFTER MAN). Thank you for your help.

Comment: @YttriaTherbium in `MS365` the answer is this `=PRODUCT(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"M","A","N"})))`

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your help! For the record, the command in portuguese reads:

=MULT(NÚM.CARACT(DIVIDIRTEXTO(D2;{"M";"T";"N"})))

Where D2 is the cell #, the separator must be semicolon as you said before. Please see 

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8n3fsj9g2m3pekjtv6u4f/Finally.png?rlkey=q6mdvmrv0r5aey5ltbrivzc3p&dl=1

Comment: Ah ok, glad you made it worked finally!

Answer (score 1):

Going to break this out into steps for you.  With office 365 you will probably have other options.  Once you see the steps, you can combine the formulas to avoid the helper columns

Step 1  Find the position of the letter

For this step I will be using the aggregate function as part of office 2013 to perform and array operation for me with out having to use an actual array.  The following formula will use FIND to determine where one of the three letters is within the text.  The AGGREGATE function with 6 will ignore all errors so letter that are not found wont be returned in the aggregate array.  The 14 in AGGREGATE tells aggregate to return the list of resulting positions in a descending order with the largest being first.  The 1 in AGGREGATE tells the function to return the value in the first position in the ordered list.

=AGGREGATE(14,6,FIND({"M","A","N"},B3),1)

Step 2  Find the number of days

The number of days that are being used is simply the position of the letter minus 1

```
=C3-1
```

Step 3 Find the number of classes

The number of classes is the length of the string code minus the position of the letter.

```
=LEN(B3)-C3
```

Step 4 Determine the workload

While your question says classes are 50 minutes long, you work load seems to be working as a value of 1 hour per class.  I made the assumption that the work load is 1 unit per class.  Therefore the formula will be number of classes times number of days:

```
=D3*E3
```

[image]

Adjust your cell references to reflect your spreadsheet.  Copy the formulas down as required.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really apreciate it. I will implement it and let you know if it worked.

Comment: It worked!!  Please see : https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3bsnlwzdmh4mjxgdtgu00/Finally_2.png?rlkey=a75alxrp4n4he40sauoydnptj&dl=1

For the record, I'll give below the commands in portuguese: (I replaced "A" by "T") 

Step 1:   =AGREGAR(14;6;LOCALIZAR({"M";"T";"N"};D2);1)

Step 2:   The same

Step 3:   =NÚM.CARACT(D2)-F2  

Step 4:  The same

Thanks a lot for your time!!